# Is there a way to clear content in a dynamic range below a table?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-tables, listobject

I have 3 tables on one sheet and right now I have vba for resizing tables 2 and 3 whenevever table 1 is resized, but would it be possible to clear all the contents below tables 2 and 3 when they are resized, because the formulas are left over

Here's the resize code :

```
Dim Tbl_2 As ListObject
Dim Tbl_1 As ListObject
Dim Tbl_3 As ListObject

Set Tbl_1 = Sheet1.ListObjects("TableQuery")
Set Tbl_2 = Sheet1.ListObjects("Table2")
Set Tbl_3 = Sheet1.ListObjects("Table3")

If Tbl_3.Range.Rows.Count <> Tbl_1.Range.Rows.Count Then
    Tbl_3.Resize Tbl_3.Range.Resize(Tbl_1.Range.Rows.Count)
End If

If Tbl_2.Range.Rows.Count <> Tbl_1.Range.Rows.Count Then
    Tbl_2.Resize Tbl_2.Range.Resize(Tbl_1.Range.Rows.Count)
End If
```

And here's the picture of what I want to ideally remove once the table is resized :

[image: image showing leftover formulas after table resizing]

Comment: Always paste the code. Could you also share more detail on how and when this should run? A screenshot of the data would also be helpful.

Comment: @VBasic2008 I've updated the question including a screenshot and the code as well. let me know if i can clear anything else up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have adjusted your code a bit as I wasn't sure if I was allowed to change both tables at the same time or if you might place certain things in between those tables so I made an extra sub to make it shorter(ish). This will make sure it only affects the cells it had prior to the resize (since you're only resizing the rows, the columns remain the same)

```
 Sub clearRowsAfterResizing()
    Dim Tbl_2 As ListObject
    Dim Tbl_1 As ListObject
    Dim Tbl_3 As ListObject
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Test2")
    Set Tbl_1 = ws.ListObjects("TableQuery")
    Set Tbl_2 = ws.ListObjects("Table2")
    Set Tbl_3 = ws.ListObjects("Table3")
    
    changeSize Tbl_2, Tbl_1, ws
    changeSize Tbl_3, Tbl_1, ws

 End Sub
 
 Sub changeSize(tblAdjust As ListObject, tblChanged As ListObject, ws As Worksheet)
    Dim lRow As Long, dif As Long, sCol As Long, lCol As Long
    lRow = tblAdjust.Range.Rows(tblAdjust.Range.Rows.Count).Row
    dif = tblAdjust.Range.Rows.Count - tblChanged.Range.Rows.Count
    If tblAdjust.Range.Rows.Count <> tblChanged.Range.Rows.Count Then
        tblAdjust.Resize tblAdjust.Range.Resize(tblChanged.Range.Rows.Count)
        If dif > 0 Then
            sCol = tblAdjust.Range.Columns(1).Column
            lCol = tblAdjust.Range.Columns(tblAdjust.Range.Columns.Count).Column
            With ws
                .Range(.Cells(lRow - dif + 1, sCol), .Cells(lRow, lCol)).Clear
            End With
        End If
    End If
 End Sub
```

Hope this helps, if you have any questions feel free to ask :)

Comment: yeah this works brilliantly, thank you so much, could you walk me through how the second if function works in the changeSize code, if it's not too much trouble

Comment: If it's about a decrease in size, it'll check the columns of the currently changing table and together with the `lRow`  from before that, you can perfectly address the range you want to clear. For example, 24 to 20 rows, dif = 4 but you need to include  the last row = 24 - 4 + 1 (which is 24,23,22,21 that you want cleared) to the lastrow and last column.

Answer (score 0):

### Resize 'Slave' Tables

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ResizeSlaveTables()

    ' Define constants.
    Const MASTER_NAME As String = "TableQuery"
    Const SLAVE_NAMES As String = "Table2,Table3"
    
    ' Reference the worksheet (by code name). Great!
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheet1
    
    ' Split the slave table names into an array.
    Dim Slaves() As String: Slaves = Split(SLAVE_NAMES, ",")

    ' Reference the master table.
    Dim mlo As ListObject: Set mlo = ws.ListObjects(MASTER_NAME)
    ' Calculate its number of rows.
    Dim mrCount As Long: mrCount = mlo.Range.Rows.Count
    
    Dim Slave, srCount As Long, WasResized As Boolean
    
    ' Loop through the slave table names.
    For Each Slave In Slaves
        ' Reference the range of the slave table.
        With ws.ListObjects(Slave).Range
            ' Calculate its number of rows.
            srCount = .Rows.Count
            ' Act per requirement.
            If mrCount <> srCount Then ' the sizes are different
                .ListObject.Resize .Resize(mrCount) ' resize the slave
                If mrCount < srCount Then ' slave size was greater
                    ' Clear 'remains' below the new size of the slave.
                    .Resize(srCount - mrCount).Offset(mrCount).Clear
                'Else ' master size was greater; do nothing
                End If
                WasResized = True ' for the message box
            'Else ' the sizes are the same; do nothing
            End If
        End With
    Next Slave
    
    If WasResized Then ' at least one was resized
        MsgBox "Slave tables resized.", vbInformation
    Else ' none were resized
        MsgBox "The slave tables were of the correct size.", vbExclamation
    End If
    
End Sub
```